# Defaulting Field When Multiple Exist On Account

Tags: sql

I have many accounts, each with multiple service codes, and each service has one location associated with it.  I want to pull up the account number and address where the service was performed.  In my data there should only be one location on the account, but because of human error there are some accounts that have a different location on each service.  I've got this so far:

```
SELECT s.acctno, l.locationaddr 
FROM service s LEFT JOIN location l on s.locationcode = l.locationcode
```

This gives me duplicate accounts for the accounts with multiple locations, and I can't have duplicates.  How do I overwrite the locationaddr to only pull up one of the locations on the account?  I've tried

```
SELECT s.acctno, (SELECT TOP 1 l.locationaddr FROM location l) 
FROM service s LEFT JOIN location l on s.locationcode = l.locationcode
```

but that gives me the same location address, regardless of if it was ever on the account.  What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a *correlated* subquery:

```
SELECT s.acctno,
       (SELECT TOP 1 l.locationaddr
        FROM location l
        WHERE s.locationcode = l.locationcode
       ) 
FROM service s;
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but that doesn't work for me.  It'll still give me the same account number twice with two separate addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my issue after several hours of trying different things.  What worked was

```
SELECT s.acctno, (SELECT TOP 1 z.locationaddr FROM 
    (SELECT s.acctno, MAX(s.serivcecode) as maxcode, s.locationcode, l.locationaddr FROM service s 
        LEFT JOIN location l on l.locationcode = s.locationcode
        GROUP BY s.acctno, s.locationcode, l.locationaddr) z WHERE s.acctno = z.acctno 
        ORDER BY maxcode DESC
FROM service s
```